# Clean URL with multiple parameters

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am using .htaccess file to achieve clean urls ,But issue is , I am unable to get 2nd parameter.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1

RewriteRule ^\/(searedness)([0-9]+)(.*)-gu([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?searedness$2=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]

</IfModule>
```

If I add second parameter like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1&location=$2
```

then , page goes 404

http://example.com/delhi/noida --> returns 404

http://example.com/delhi/ --> working fine with below rule only

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1
```

Comment: You only have one group in the last pattern, but you reference two with `$1` and `$2`, what do you intend to have there?

Comment: I did not understand your question. ' One group in the last pattern ' means ? Sorry but i have very little knowledge about regex.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1` works because `$1` refers to the value captured with the first parenthesized construct in the regex pattern. You do not have the second `(...)` there.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1&location=$2` like this ? It is showing 500 internal server error

Comment: Of course, it is not correct. Do you want to match 2 subparts? Try `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`

Comment: Now it is working with 2 parameters, but not working with 1 parameter. and shows 404 page when I pass only city name. Can i make this parameters optional ? thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding two lines: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1&location=$2 [L]` and then `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ result-by-city.php?city=$1 [L]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173457/discussion-between-nirali-joshi-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule for `:city/location/speciality`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?city=$1&location=$2&speciality=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This single rule will support all of these URILs:

```
example.com/delhi
example.com/delhi/noida 
example.com/delhi/noida/dentist
```